# How do I deploy my custom search code inside Access 2013?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

I am playing around with some fuzzy text searching ideas and have a C# API as follows:

```
namespace MySearcher
{
    class FuzzyText1
    {
        private string m_Query;
        public void RegisterQuery(string q);

        public bool IsHit(string target);
    }
}
```

The client defines a text query once via RegisterQuery, then calls IsHit for each string to be searched by that query.

Is it possible to have this code called as part of an Access 2013 search? Either by having a custom Access form, or an API that be called externally  I would like these search methods to be used when a search is performed on a specified column of text in an Access table.

My own research has led me to adding VBA custom code, but is it possible to call the C# API? And what has to be done on the Access side to make it work?

Comment: i dont think so. Access forms were made to work with the data directly. As for VBA, i dont think you can make an external call like that.

Comment: Is your c# code too complicated or reliant on .net to be converted into vb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well call .Net code from Access. The trick is making your .Net DLL COM-visible.

Check out [A Beginner’s Guide to calling a .NET Library from Access](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/08/25/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-access/).

One detail: make sure you explicitly set your VS Project to the same bitness as your MSOffice installation. So if you're using the 32 bit version of Office, set your project to `x86`, **not** `AnyCPU`...